# ARRAY of method functions

Tags: java, android

Is it posible to store functions in an array in java?
Like for example..

```
public void getMyname(){

// do something here;

}

public void getLastname(){

//do something here;
}

Array arr = {getLastName,getMyname};
```

Like that? if so is it right?

Comment: That is not possible (Java <= 7) - Not directly.  But if you explain your problem (context) somebody can help you to get close to that. ... in some cases you can use `Method` class (reflection api) or something like command pattern, etc ... depends on the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store methods in arrays in Java, because methods aren't first-class objects in Java. It's a reason some people prefer to use other languages like Python, Scheme, etc.

The work-around is to create an interface which contains one method, then create four classes implementing that interface - the MoveRight, MoveLeft, etc... classes. Then you can store instances of those classes in your array and call them all the same way.

```
public enum Level1 implements Explorable{
    ROOM1 {
        public void explore() {
            // fight monster
        }
    }, ROOM2 {
        public void explore() {
            // solve riddle
        }
    }, ROOM3 {
        public void explore() {
            // rescue maiden
        }
    };

}

public interface Explorable{
    public abstract void explore();    
}

public static void move(Explorable[] adjacentNodes, int index)
{
    adjacentNodes[index].explore();
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is too much of asking but can you give me an example?

Comment: I dont know where should this code.. is it all in the main activity?

Answer (score 1):

Well You can do this..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String[] arrwow = {wow(),wow2()};
    Toast.makeText(this, arrwow[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

public String wow(){

    String wow = "wow";
    return wow;
}
public String wow2(){
    String wow2 = "wow2";
    return wow2;
}
```

Works on me.. ^_^ Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot store functions in Java. How about some object orientation? Create a `Person` class that encapsulate the name information:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }        

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Instantiate it:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setFirstName("John");
person.setLastName("Doe");
```

Now that you have an object to work with, and I would advise you to pass around instances of `Person` for as long as possible, because that means that the type information will be preserved. Compare with de-referencing the person names to a String array, it is less obvious what kind of data you are dealing with (an array of names, colors, country codes, etc, ?).

That said, if you insist on de-referencing the name data, it is not difficult to create a `String` array or `List<String>` if you chose to do so:

```
String[] nameArray = {person.getFirstName(), person.getLastName()};

// or

List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
nameList.add(person.getFirstName());
nameList.add(person.getLastName());
```